# How do I check if each UITextField in an Array has a user input?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextfield

I have a list of `UITextFields` in an `Array` for users to key in phone numbers. When I click the Send Button, it will connect with my server to send an automated message to the numbers listed. This portion works well. What I want to do now is to check which of the `UITextFields` has a phone number in it and to check if it has the prefix + before it connects to my server. If any of the `UITextField` has a phone number without the prefix +, the border color of that `UITextField` should change colours. If the `UITextField` does not have a phone number, no action should be taken. How do I go about achieving that?

This is the portion of the code that I need help in

```
    @IBAction func sendbutton(_ sender: Any) {

        var numArray: Array<Any>

        numArray = [phonenumber.text!, phonenumber1.text!, phonenumber2.text!, phonenumber3.text!]

        let myColor = UIColor.red

        for num in numArray {
            if (num as AnyObject).hasPrefix("+") {
                print("Has + symbol")

            } else {
                print("Does Not Have Symbol")

            }
        }
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you declare `numArray` as `[Any]`?  It's clearly `[String]`. Actually don't annotate a type at all. The compiler can infer the type.

Comment: You clearly defined your step-by-step end result. Just follow the steps and you get all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse over the `array` of `textFields` and for each `textField` validate the `text` for first `character` is `"+"`. If not set its `borderColor`.

```
var textFields = [phonenumber, phonenumber1, phonenumber2, phonenumber3]
var numArray = [String]()

textFields.forEach {
    if let text = $0.text, text.first == "+" {
        numArray.append(text)
        $0.layer.borderWidth = 0.0 //To reset the textField if it didn't validate earlier
    } else {
        $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        $0.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm @PGDev. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should loop over an array of strings, instead loop over the text fields so you can set the color directly

```
var textFields: Array<UITextField> = [phonenumber, phonenumber1, phonenumber2, phonenumber3]
var numbersToSend = [String]()
let myColor = UIColor.red

for textField in textFields {
    let number = textField.text ?? ""
    if validatePhoneNumber(number) { //extract validation into separate function for clarity
        numbersToSend.append(number)
    } else {
        textField.backgroundColor = myColor //or whatever property you want to change
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution i'll work.

```
private var arrTextFilds = [phonenumber.text ?? "", phonenumber1.text ?? "", 
phonenumber2.text!, phonenumber3.text ?? ""]
private var numArray : [String] = []
arrTextFilds {
   if let text = $0.text,text.hasPrefix(“+”) {
       numArray.append(text)
       $0.layer.borderWidth = 0.0 
   } else {
      $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
      $0.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
  }
}
```